# For a convergent series, is the limit of partial sum is always equal to the infinite sum of the series?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Let $ (x_k)_{k\in \mathbb{N} }$ be an infinite sequence of the real numbers. For $ n\in \mathbb{N} $, define the partial sum $ s_n$ as

$$ s_n = \sum_{k = 1}^n x_k $$
Then we have a new infinite sequence $ (s_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N} }$. Now, suppose this new sequence converges, i.e., there is a $ L \in  \mathbb{R}$ such that for all $ \epsilon > 0 $, there exists a $ N \in \mathbb{N}$, such that for all $ n > N$, it is the case that
$$ |s_n - L|< \epsilon . \tag{1}$$

Now, consider the $\epsilon$ is the same as in $ ( 1 ) $, then my question is, is it always the case that
$$ \left|\sum_{k\in \mathbb{N}} x_k - L\right| < \epsilon\; ?\tag{2}$$
If yes, how can I prove this?

I thought of using $ ( 1 ) $ to prove $ ( 2) $, but I think we can not do this as $ s_n $ in $ ( 1 ) $ consists of the sum of a finite number of elements that are $ x_1, x_2, ..., x_n$, whereas $ \sum_{k\in \mathbb{N}} x_k$ in $ ( 2) $ consists of the sum of an infinite number of elements.

Could you please help me in proving or disproving the equation $ ( 2) $.

Comment: What's your definition of the infinite sum if not the limit of the partial sums?

Comment: This is literally the definition of convergence of a series.

Answer (score 5):

The definition of an infinite sum of a series is the limit of its partial sums, so by definition, the infinite sum always equals the limit of the partial sums. In other words, the very definition of $\sum_{k=1}^\infty x_k$ is the limit $L$ of the sequence $(s_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, i.e. $\sum_{k=1}^\infty x_k=L$.

Comment: Ok, then suppose there exists a god who knows the exact value of the sum $ \sum_{ k \in \mathbb{N}} x_k$, and suppose that value is not equal to the limit of a partial sum. Then what?

Comment: @RobinKurtz You're asking a more philosophical rather than mathematical question at that point, but in terms of pure mathematics, the definition of the sum $\sum_{k=1}^\infty x_k$ is equal to the limit of the partial sum, so that definition can't be violated within the realm of pure mathematics.

Comment: @RobinKurtz well then you have to explain first what it means to be "the exact value" of the sum of $\sum_{k\in\mathbb{N}x_k}$

Comment: @ioveri ; sum of all the elements of the sequence $ (x_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}} $ but not in the sense of limit of partial sum.